# Nativescript FCM firebase plugin

Tags: android, firebase, nativescript

I am trying to implement push notification which are received from firebase's FCM. I am receiving the notifications for both platforms but when the app is in background, the onMessageReceivedCallback method works great on IOS but on Android it seems like its working funny. It wont print any logs and the if I alert the Message, it would be undefined. All while this works great on IOS. I am struggling with this for 2 days.

Also, on IOS it looks like the app is resuming when taping the notification, while on Android it looks like the app is restarting(first it shows white screen which takes some time and then the actual app shows up)

Comment: Are you trying to print like `message.title` or `message.data` in the console? Is it undefined on Android but same works on iOS?

Comment: I am trying to print either message or message.title yes. Undefined on android but same code works on iOS

Comment: But the Notification is displayed correctly still?